# How to create correct JSONArray in Java using JSONObject

Tags: java, json, arrays

how can I create a JSON Object like the following, in Java using JSONObject ?

```
{
    "employees": [
        {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"}, 
        {"firstName": "Anna", "lastName": "Smith"}, 
        {"firstName": "Peter", "lastName": "Jones"}
    ],
    "manager": [
        {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"}, 
        {"firstName": "Anna", "lastName": "Smith"}, 
        {"firstName": "Peter", "lastName": "Jones"}
    ]
}
```

I've found a lot of example, but not my exactly JSONArray string.

Answer (score 278):

Here is some code using java 6 to get you started:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
jo.put("firstName", "John");
jo.put("lastName", "Doe");

JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
ja.put(jo);

JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
mainObj.put("employees", ja);
```

**Edit:** Since there has been a lot of confusion about `put` vs `add` here I will attempt to explain the difference.  In java 6 [org.json.JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) contains the `put` method and in java 7 [javax.json](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) contains the `add` method.

An example of this using the builder pattern in java 7 looks something like this:

```
JsonObject jo = Json.createObjectBuilder()
  .add("employees", Json.createArrayBuilder()
    .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
      .add("firstName", "John")
      .add("lastName", "Doe")))
  .build();
```

Comment: maybe also wrap into try/catch? (or the method has to have throws statement)

Comment: JSONArray does not have a put method.

Comment: use add instead of put

Comment: I'm a little confused by the docs on JsonArray... can you explain which put method takes two strings as arguments? e.g. 
put("lastName", "Doe"); http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: @user3388884 JSONArray doesn't contain a put method that takes two strings.  But I'm not using JSONArray there I'm using a JSONObject. http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: Is there a way to implement JsonObject and JsonArray similar to JSONObject and JSONArray? Meaning creating empty objects and then adding components in subsequent methods, instaed of all at once as in JsonObject and JsonArray?

Comment: @PT_C yep JsonObject jo = Json.createObjectBuilder(); jo.add("firstName", "John"); jo.add("lastName", "Doe"); jo.build();

Comment: What should I import to make my ide understand Json.createObjectBuilder()?

Comment: What version of java are you using?  You need to be using java 7 or above.

Comment: @Jim JSONArray does have put method

Comment: Here's a short tutorial that demonstrates [creating a JSONObject and a JSONArray](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qEpxIARKxE)  using org.json.

Comment: @Grammin how to add ja to mainObj without key(employees)? like {[{--},{--},{--}]}

Comment: @ArnoldBrown In order to add an array to mainObj it has to have a key.

Answer (score 17):

I suppose you're getting this JSON from a server or a file, and you want to create a JSONArray object out of it.

```
String strJSON = ""; // your string goes here
JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray) new JSONTokener(strJSON).nextValue();
// once you get the array, you may check items like
JSONOBject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 16):

Small **reusable method can be written** for creating person json object to avoid duplicate code

```
JSONObject  getPerson(String firstName, String lastName){
   JSONObject person = new JSONObject();
   person .put("firstName", firstName);
   person .put("lastName", lastName);
   return person ;
} 

public JSONObject getJsonResponse(){

    JSONArray employees = new JSONArray();
    employees.put(getPerson("John","Doe"));
    employees.put(getPerson("Anna","Smith"));
    employees.put(getPerson("Peter","Jones"));

    JSONArray managers = new JSONArray();
    managers.put(getPerson("John","Doe"));
    managers.put(getPerson("Anna","Smith"));
    managers.put(getPerson("Peter","Jones"));

    JSONObject response= new JSONObject();
    response.put("employees", employees );
    response.put("manager", managers );
    return response;
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Please try this ... hope it helps

```
JSONObject jsonObj1=null;
JSONObject jsonObj2=null;
JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
JSONArray array2=new JSONArray();

jsonObj1=new JSONObject();
jsonObj2=new JSONObject();


array.put(new JSONObject().put("firstName", "John").put("lastName","Doe"))
.put(new JSONObject().put("firstName", "Anna").put("v", "Smith"))
.put(new JSONObject().put("firstName", "Peter").put("v", "Jones"));

array2.put(new JSONObject().put("firstName", "John").put("lastName","Doe"))
.put(new JSONObject().put("firstName", "Anna").put("v", "Smith"))
.put(new JSONObject().put("firstName", "Peter").put("v", "Jones"));

jsonObj1.put("employees", array);
jsonObj1.put("manager", array2);

Response response = null;
response = Response.status(Status.OK).entity(jsonObj1.toString()).build();
return response;
```