# How to display data from servlet using json?

Tags: java, jquery, json, html, servlets

I want to display data from servlet which returns json. No errors on the console and also I don't have the result.

`file.js`:

```
$("#json_disp").click(function(){
$.ajax({
url : 'Servlet',
dataType: 'json',
success : function(json) {
$("#res").html(json.user);
}
});
```

`file.html`:

```
<body>
    <input type="button" value="display" id="json_disp">
    <div id="res"></div>
</body>
```

`Servlet.java`

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
User u = new User();
u.setId(1);
u.setName("Jhon");
json.put("user", u);
out.println(json);
out.flush();
```

Comment: what about debugging ? The server is called ? what about the debugguer in your browser ? is there any errors or informations ?

Comment: no there isn't any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
     User u = new User();  
     u.setId(1);  
     u.setName("Jhon");  

    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    obj.put("u_id",user.getId());
    obj.put("u_name",user.getName());
    out.println(json);
    out.flush();
```

and change the display names accordingly in the jquery snippet.

Comment: you are welcome, your understanding of the JSONObject class needs to be improved :)

Comment: thanks GionJh, i want to display  the information of  2 users, u.setId(1);  
     u.setName("Jhon");  u.setId(2);  
     u.setName("Mike") . i tried to do this attempt :  JSONArray list = new JSONArray(); 
   User u = new User();
   u.setId(1);
   u.setName("Jhon");
   u.setId(2);
   u.setName("Mike");
      list.add(u.getId()); 
    list.add(u.getName());
   out.print(list);
    out.flush();              but just the information of one user is displayed

Comment: this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983185/how-to-create-correct-jsonarray-in-java-using-jsonobject

Comment: i tried this attempt :JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
jo.put("firstName", "John");
jo.put("lastName", "Doe");
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
ja.add(jo);
JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
mainObj.put("employees", ja);
out.println(mainObj); and in the js file i wrote $("#res").html(json.mainObj); but i don't have any result