# Java List to json format

Tags: java, json

Here is my code :

```
public String getList() throws JSONException {
        List<User> data = member.getCurrentMembers() ;
        for (User u : data) {
            JSONObject datas = new JSONObject();
            datas.put("name", u.getUserName());
            datas.put("account", u.getAccount());
            datas.put("edit", u.getUserId());
            datas.put("id", u.getUserId());
            System.out.println(datas);  
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Now it will print  :

```
{"name":"aa","id":1,"edit":1,"account":"aa@qq.com"}
{"name":"qq","id":2,"edit":2,"account":"qq@qq.com"}
{"name":"ww","id":3,"edit":3,"account":"ww@qq.com"}
```

And the json format I want is  :

```
{ 
  "Data": [
    {"name":"aa","id":1,"edit":1,"account":"aa@qq.com"},
    {"name":"qq","id":2,"edit":2,"account":"qq@qq.com"},
    {"name":"ww","id":3,"edit":3,"account":"ww@qq.com"},     
  ]
}
```

Waht can I do ??
Please guide me .  thank you

Comment: Try wrapping all these `JSONObjects` up to a `JSONArray`

Comment: How can I put each data together??

Comment: Use a JSONArray. The answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983185/how-to-create-correct-jsonarray-in-java-using-jsonobject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can do the trick

```
public String getList() throws JSONException {
    List<User> data = member.getCurrentMembers() ;
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    for (User u : data) {
        JSONObject datas = new JSONObject();
        datas.put("name", u.getUserName());
        datas.put("account", u.getAccount());
        datas.put("edit", u.getUserId());
        datas.put("id", u.getUserId());
        array.put(datas);
    }
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    result.put("Data", array);
}
```

Hope it helps
Dan