# Create JSONObject with JAVA

Tags: java, json

I need to create JSONObject with JAVA. Can someone help me? JSON should look like this:

```
{
  "text":[
    "Java",
    "JavaC"
  ],
  "metaData":{
    "fileName":"javaLangSpec.txt",
    "fileSize":"900KB",
    "fileCreationDate":"January 23, 1996 at 12: 52PM"
  }
}
```

Comment: use this package `org.json.JSONObject`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create correct JsonArray in Java using JsonObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983185/how-to-create-correct-jsonarray-in-java-using-jsonobject)

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple:

```
 String jsonString = "{\n" +
                "  \"text\":[\n" +
                "    \"Java\",\n" +
                "    \"JavaC\"\n" +
                "  ],\n" +
                "  \"metaData\":{\n" +
                "    \"fileName\":\"javaLangSpec.txt\",\n" +
                "    \"fileSize\":\"900KB\",\n" +
                "    \"fileCreationDate\":\"January 23, 1996 at 12: 52PM\"\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Comment: @StephenP The question is about `Java` not `javascript`.