# how to pass array of markers from servlet to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, jsp, servlets

I want pass array of markes to javascript on jsp page to show them on google map.
In servlet I load array of markers from database, but I don't know how to pass them to javascript.
Thi is my servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) `throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub`
    PlaceDao placeDao = new PlaceDao();
    ArrayList<Place> pList = new ArrayList<Place>();
    try {
        pList = placeDao.readData();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Marker marker = new Marker();
    ArrayList<Marker> mList = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    for (int i = 0; i < pList.size(); ++i)
    {
        marker.setLatitude(pList.get(i).getLatitude());
        marker.setLongitude(pList.get(i).getLongitude());
        mList.add(marker);
    }
    request.setAttribute("marker", mList);

    request.getRequestDispatcher("pages/location.jsp").forward(request, response);
}`
```

and my jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>


<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">

</script>

<script>
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850);

    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center : myCenter,
            zoom : 5,
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),
                mapProp);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position : myCenter,
        });

        marker.setMap(map);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width: 500px; height: 380px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So instead of `var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850);`
I want pass my array. I think that could be done with JSON but I don't sure and don't know how.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Few things to nottice:

- You cannot read the Java `List` in javascript.
- You must return the result in some way to be able to access in the javascript (client) side.

---

## How to get the list in the client side?

You can choose one of this 2 options:

- Use an Ajax call (for example):

  ```
  $.get( "urlToMethod", { 
          "someVariable": someValue 
      }).done(function( data ) {
          // in data you have the list of markers
      }).error(function (data) {
          // in data you have exception or the error
      });
  ```

  Java mapping:

  ```
  @RequestMapping(value = "urlToMethod")
  public String[] getMarkers (
          HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
          HttpServletResponse httpResponse,
          @RequestParam(value = "someVariable") String someVariable) {

      // get the markers and return a String[] or JSONArray!!!
  }
  ```
- Put the list into an JSP fied and read it in the script:

  Java side (create a `HelperClass` if necessary)

  ```
  model.addAttribute("markers", markersList);
  ```

  Javascript

  ```
  markers = $("#markers").val();
  ```

  JSP

  ```
  <form:hidden path="markers" id="markers" />
  ```

---

## How to read the Java `List` in javascript:

Also here you can use any of this options:

- You cannot read a List in javascript, but you can read a `String` or `String[]` (don't use double or float for the GPS lat/long due loosing of precision).
- Create a JSONArray of the markers [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18983290/3850595):

---

**NOTE:** I assume you have `JQuery` in your project, also be careful because in Ajax solutions `Spring` is used, [check here if you don't have it in your project](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/04/jquery-ajax-request-response-java.html).