# To get json of requied form

Tags: java, json

I need to create a json like this

```
[
    {
        "name": "Michael Bruce",
        "gender": "Male",
        "designation": "System Architect"
    },
    {
        "name": "Jennifer Winters",
        "gender": "Female",
        "designation": "Senior Programmer"
    },
    {
        "name": "Donna Fox",
        "gender": "Female",
        "designation": "Office Manager"
    },
    {
        "name": "Howard Hatfield",
        "gender": "Male",
        "designation": "Customer Support"
    }
]
```

I tried to make it with this program ...

```
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
 import java.io.FileWriter;



 public class hello{

 public static void getJSONArray() throws JSONException {

           /* JSONArray jo= new JSONArray();

            JSONObject obj1= new JSONObject();
            obj1.put("A","a");

            JSONObject obj2= new JSONObject();
            obj2.put("B","b");

            JSONObject obj3= new JSONObject();
            obj3.put("B","c");

            jo.put(obj1);
            jo.put(obj2);
            jo.put(obj3);

            System.out.println(jo.toString());*/


            /*-----------------------------*/
            JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
            for(int p=0;p<5;p++){
                JSONObject jo1= new JSONObject ();
           String strr= Integer.toString(p);
           String strr2=Integer.toString(p+1);
            jo1.put("name", strr );
            jo1.put("gender", strr2);
            jo1.put("designation",strr2);
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
            ja.put(jo1);


            mainObj.accumulate("employees", ja);
            }
            /*System.out.println(mainObj);
              PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("neww.json", "UTF-8");
            writer.println("The first line");
            writer.println("The second line");
            writer.close();*/
            try{
             // create new file
             String content = mainObj.toString();

             String path="E:\\a\\hi.txt";
             File file = new File(path);

                // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                // write in file
                bw.write(content);
                // close connection
                bw.close();
          }catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println(e);
          }




 }

            public static void main(String args[]) throws JSONException{
            getJSONArray();

            }

            }
```

but i am getting json of the form as

```
{
    "employees": [
        [{
            "gender": "1",
            "name": "0",
            "designation": "1"
        }],
        [{
            "gender": "2",
            "name": "1",
            "designation": "2"
        }],
        [{
            "gender": "3",
            "name": "2",
            "designation": "3"
        }],
        [{
            "gender": "4",
            "name": "3",
            "designation": "4"
        }],
        [{
            "gender": "5",
            "name": "4",
            "designation": "5"
        }]
    ]
}
```

What change should i make in my java code to get the json of the type i have shown first.I have written my json to a file,.
I tried this link
[How to create correct JsonArray in Java using JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983185/how-to-create-correct-jsonarray-in-java-using-jsonobject)

But i am getting output as

```
{
    "employees": [{
        "gender": "5",
        "name": "4",
        "designation": "5"
    }]
}
```

Comment: What do you think `accumulate` does? Why are you using that?

Comment: the Java Source Code for JSONObject and the difference between accumulate and put is that with accumulate(String key,Object Value), if there exists some value for "key" then the Object is checked for being an array, if it is an array then the "value" is added to the array else an array is created for this key.

In put, however, the key if it exists, it's value is replaced by the value - "value"

Comment: I tried the link given above but i get output as.........

{
 "employees": [{
  "gender": "5",
  "name": "4",
  "designation": "5"
 }]
}

Comment: Adapt it. If you don't need the root JSON object, don't use it. Just keep the `JSONArray`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis
i didn't get you

Comment: In the JSON you posted in your previous comment, you have a `JSONObject` which has a member called `employees` which is a `JSONArray`. You don't need that `JSONObject`, all you need is the `JSONArray`, so just keep that.

Comment: ok but even then i am missing jsons name:0,name:1 ,name 3 ... all i am getting is that single element of an array

Comment: Just add those `JSONObject`s to the `JSONArray`. Are you confused about the [JSON format](http://json.org/)? The first snippet you posted in your question is a JSON array containing a bunch of JSON objects. So create a `JSONArray`, then for each `name`, create and add a `JSONObject` to that `JSONArray`.