# How to create a JSON Array of Objects?

Tags: java, json

I am collecting data from a website using Java Regex. From Matched groups I want to create JSON Array of Objects like this :-

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create correct JsonArray in Java using JSONObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983185/how-to-create-correct-jsonarray-in-java-using-jsonobject)

Comment: Even the posted json is the same.