# Reading a JSON file with multiple attributes

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to read a JSON file that contains an array of different bikes. When trying to print out the bikes to the java console, i keep getting a null point exception. I'm going to make it so that all the bikes are made into object, but for now just looking on how to print them out.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("src/bikes.json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        //System.out.println(jsonObject);

        JSONArray bikeList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("BikeList");

        Iterator<String> iterator = bikeList.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

JSON File:

```
 {
    "Search": {
        "BikeList": [
            {
                "weight": "14.8",
                "colour": "Blue",
                "price": 149.99,
                "name": "Hybrid Pro"
            },
            {
                "weight": "15.8",
                "colour": "Red",
                "price": 249.99,
                "name": "Slant comp"
            },
            {
                "weight": "17.9",
                "colour": "Pink",
                "price": 500.00,
                "name": "Charm"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Search").get("BikeList") ? You need to access  `Search` first and then get `BikeList` from the object.

Comment: why not try using Jackson Json library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to get the "Search" object. And also you can't just print the object. You need to fetch all the attributes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("src/bikes.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            // System.out.println(jsonObject);

            JSONObject search = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("Search");
            JSONArray bikeList = (JSONArray) search.get("BikeList");

            for (int i = 0; i < bikeList.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject bike = (JSONObject) bikeList.get(i);
                System.out.println("********************");
                System.out.println("Weight: " + bike.get("weight"));
                System.out.println("Colour: " + bike.get("colour"));
                System.out.println("Price: " + bike.get("price"));
                System.out.println("Name: " + bike.get("name"));
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why Don't you try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("src/bikes.json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        //System.out.println(jsonObject);

   *JSONArray Search= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Search");
   JSONArray bikeList = (JSONArray) Search.get("BikeList");*

        Iterator<String> iterator = bikeList.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your object is null because, it does not exist. For that you need to have a schema for JSON document like this,

```
{
    "BikeList": [
```

The above code contains, a first-level `BikeList`. Which you would then capture from the code. This is the mistake in your code. I believe, you need to read the `Search` node first, and then move down to the next one to capture the list,

```
 {
    "Search": { // This one first.
        "BikeList": [
```

That way, you would first require to get the `Search` object, then get the `BikeList`, otherwise it will always be null.

```
// Search is an object, not an array.
JSONObject search = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("Search");

// Find the list in the search object.
```

Rest of code is the one you already have. This would get the list for you.

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
JSONArray bikeList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("BikeList");
```

you have to use the arrayBuilder like this

```
 JsonArray array = Json.createArrayBuilder().build();
```

in an example:

```
 [
     { "type": "home", "number": "212 555-1234" },
     { "type": "fax", "number": "646 555-4567" }
 ]



 JsonArray value = Json.createArrayBuilder()
     .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
         .add("type", "home")
         .add("number", "212 555-1234"))
     .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
         .add("type", "fax")
         .add("number", "646 555-4567"))
     .build();
```

quick info here
[JsonArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html)

or here
[How to create correct JsonArray in Java using JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983185/how-to-create-correct-jsonarray-in-java-using-jsonobject)

Answer (score 2):

Create java Pojos and annotate with Jackson 2

```
package com.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "Search" })
public class Bike {

    @JsonProperty("Search")
    private Search search;

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     * 
     */
    public Bike() {
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param search
     */
    public Bike(final Search search) {
        super();
        this.search = search;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Search")
    public Search getSearch() {
        return search;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Search")
    public void setSearch(final Search search) {
        this.search = search;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bike [search=" + search + "]";
    }

}



package com.example;

import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "BikeList" })
public class Search {

    @JsonProperty("BikeList")
    private List<BikeList> bikeList = null;

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     * 
     */
    public Search() {
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param bikeList
     */
    public Search(final List<BikeList> bikeList) {
        super();
        this.bikeList = bikeList;
    }

    @JsonProperty("BikeList")
    public List<BikeList> getBikeList() {
        return bikeList;
    }

    @JsonProperty("BikeList")
    public void setBikeList(final List<BikeList> bikeList) {
        this.bikeList = bikeList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Search [bikeList=" + bikeList + "]";
    }

}





package com.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "weight", "colour", "price", "name" })
public class BikeList {

    @JsonProperty("weight")
    private String weight;
    @JsonProperty("colour")
    private String colour;
    @JsonProperty("price")
    private Double price;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     * 
     */
    public BikeList() {
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param colour
     * @param price
     * @param weight
     * @param name
     */
    public BikeList(final String weight, final String colour, final Double price, final String name) {
        super();
        this.weight = weight;
        this.colour = colour;
        this.price = price;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("weight")
    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    @JsonProperty("weight")
    public void setWeight(final String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @JsonProperty("colour")
    public String getColour() {
        return colour;
    }

    @JsonProperty("colour")
    public void setColour(final String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    @JsonProperty("price")
    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @JsonProperty("price")
    public void setPrice(final Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BikeList [weight=" + weight + ", colour=" + colour + ", price=" + price + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

}


Then employ Jackson to read input json and convert to Java Objects

package com.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader;

public class Stackoverflow {

    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final ObjectReader OBJECT_READER_BIKE = OBJECT_MAPPER.readerFor(Bike.class);

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {

        final Bike bike = OBJECT_READER_BIKE.readValue(new File("input/bike.json"));

        System.out.println(bike);

    }

}
```

output obtained:-

```
Bike [search=Search [bikeList=[BikeList [weight=14.8, colour=Blue, price=149.99, name=Hybrid Pro], BikeList [weight=15.8, colour=Red, price=249.99, name=Slant comp], BikeList [weight=17.9, colour=Pink, price=500.0, name=Charm]]]]
```

Comment: I agree with this solution. Just a note, the Annotation are not mandatory if the properties have same names in POJO and json