# Java: Converting a String to JSONArray, or Spliting an String the right way

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have an unusual qustion which looks as the following:

**Question 1:** How can i split a String the right way so that i get the json-File Entries separated from one another.

**Or Question:** How do i convert a String to JSONArray.

**The JSON:**

```
[
   {
   "id":"123483",
      "content":{
         "amount":"460",
         "price":"2.15",
         "name":"Post-it Block weiß",
         "weight":"0.3",
         "category":"Notizzettel"
 } 
},
   {
      "id":"501993",
      "content":{
         "amount":"83",
         "price":"25.0",
         "name":"Trennstreifen 5x 100 bunt",
         "weight":"0.024",
         "category":"Register"

   }

}
]
```

*What i tried:* // content succesfully encapsulates all the json content.

```
Path path = Paths.get("src/com/json/inventory.json");
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), Charset.defaultCharset());


JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(); 
JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(content);
jsonArray.put(jsnobject);
```

The Errors with JSONArray: [Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OERd.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your content is an array, not a single object.

Try `new JSONArray(content);`

Or use a library like Jackson or Gson to read the file into a list of POJO classes

Also note that the src folder does not exist at runtime for your code. The standard layout for placing resource files looks like this

```
src
  main
    java 
      Code.java 
  resources
    file.json
```

And you use ClassLoader to read the file

Comment: It did worked greatly, now i need to find a way to acces the contents within. What do i mean: if you do jsonArray.get(0) = you get the first Entrie in the json Array, however i seem to not be able to get things such as Id, content etc. You know how to do that?

Comment: I would recommend researching jsonpath

Answer (score 0):

You must do `new JSONArray(content);` not `new JSONObject(content);`

Because if you do the second way, java try to cast the array into a single object.

You can see more information in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983185/how-to-create-correct-jsonarray-in-java-using-jsonobject)