# How to convert List<JsonObject> to JsonArray in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, json, jsonp

I have written a code, where I need to create a JSON format output from a "select * query". So far I am able to get the output like this, but I have to wrap it up inside "users"

```
{
  "displayName": "Tony Stark",
  "givenName": "Tony",
  "surname": "Stark"
},
{
  "displayName": "James Martin",
  "givenName": "James",
  "surname": "Martin"
}
```

I need something like this:

```
{
   "users": 
      [
            {
                  "displayName": "Tony Stark",
                  "givenName": "Toney",
                  "surname": "Stark"
            },
            {
                  "displayName": "James Martin",
                  "givenName": "James",
                  "surname": "Martin"
            }
      ]
}
```

Please help me out in this.

Comment: Please update the question with code where you are querying database and converting to json,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create correct JSONArray in Java using JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983185/how-to-create-correct-jsonarray-in-java-using-jsonobject)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible if you create a model class named Users, map it properly along it with it's attributes so it will show exactly as shown by you in the screenshot.
Attaching reference model class.

[image]

Comment: List<JsonObject> jObj = getJSONFormat(resultSet);

Comment: I have a List as given above, I have the resultSet which is a List as well, if you print this you will get what I am getting now,

Comment: Can you tell me how can I wrap this list inside "users"

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy if add a wrap class and convert it to json

```
import java.util.List;

public class UserWrap {
    private List<User> users;

    public UserWrap(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```