# How to send the multiple jsonobjects inside the JSONArray to the api using retrofit android

Tags: java, android, retrofit2.6

My Format

```
  { 
      "iList": [
        {
          "ADDRESS1": "string",
          "CITY": "string",
          "COUNTRY": "string",
          "EMAIL_ADDRESS": "string",
           "FIRST_NAME": "string",
         
          "LAST_NAME": "string",
          "PRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBER": "string",
          "STATE_PROVINCE": "string",
          "ZIP_CODE": "string"
        }
      ],
      "iaList": [
        {
          "ATTRIBUTE_NAME": "string",
          "CUSTOM_PERMISSION": "string",
          "Id": "string",
          "GLOBAL_PERMISSION": "string"
        },
       {
          "ATTRIBUTE_NAME": "string",
          "CUSTOM_PERMISSION": "string",
          "Id": "string",
          "GLOBAL_PERMISSION": "string"
        },
    
    {
          "ATTRIBUTE_NAME": "string",
          "CUSTOM_PERMISSION": "string",
          "Id": "string",
          "GLOBAL_PERMISSION": "string"
        }
    
    
      ],
      "Uplift": [
        {
          "AGE": 0,
          "AUTOMOBILE": "string",
          "CHILD_AGES": "string",
          "DATE_OF_BIRTH": "string",
          "EDUCATION": "string",
          "GENDER": "string",
        }
      ]
    }
```

I have created a main model class with List and each individual model class. But i have no idea of doing iaList. How can i pass multiple json object inside json array . Please anyone help me

Comment: *How can i pass multiple json object inside json array* - does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983185/how-to-create-correct-jsonarray-in-java-using-jsonobject) answer you question?

Comment: @Tamir how can I pass that whold json object to API

Comment: JsonObject mainJsonObject = new JsonObject();

JsonArray jsonArray1 = new JsonArray();
jsonArray1.add(youriList):

mainJsonObject.add("iList", jsonArray1);

JsonArray jsonArray2 = new JsonArray();
jsonArray2.add(youriaList):

mainJsonObject.add("iaList", jsonArray2);

JsonArray jsonArray3 = new JsonArray();
jsonArray3.add(yourUplift):

mainJsonObject.add("Uplift", jsonArray3);

and Pass mainJsonObject to api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create correct JSONArray in Java using JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983185/how-to-create-correct-jsonarray-in-java-using-jsonobject)